# Find all possible combinations of words in given format

Tags: prolog, substitution, constraint-programming

I have 100 000 lines long dictionary:

```
w([w,o,r,d]).
w([h,a,p,p,y]).
w([q,u,e,s,t,i,o,n]).
...
```

Now I am working on a script that will return all possible words, that meet given format.

For example:

```
w([A,B,C]), w([B,C]), A \== B, A \== C, B \== C.
```

I've found the source that makes all variables different:

```
alldif([]).
alldif([E|Es]) :-
   maplist(dif(E), Es),
   alldif(Es).
```

So now I call:

```
w([A,B,C]), w([B,C]), alldif([A,B,C]).
```

Now I want that the variable A is one of [a,e,i,o,t,l]. I can do that using:

```
member(A, [a,e,i,o,t,l]).
```

But is it faster (?) using constraint programming with:

```
A in [a,e,i,o,t,l]
```

and

```
all_different([A,B,C]).
```

I am kind of stuck right now. The idea's been to generate all possible options in .txt file line by line.

I managed to concatenate words into statement using:

```
g([A,B,C], W1), g([B,C], W2), alldif([A,B,C]), buildStat([W1,W2], Statement).
```

Where:

```
g(Format, Word):-
    list_to_set(Format, Uniques),
    alldif(Uniques),
    w(Format),
    atomic_list_concat(Format, '', Atom), atom_string(Atom, Word).

insertSpaces([A], [A]).
insertSpaces([Word | Rest], OutWords):-
    insertSpaces(Rest, OutWordsRest),
    OutWords = [Word, " " | OutWordsRest].


buildStat(Words, Statement):-
    insertSpaces(Words, OutWords),
    with_output_to(atom(Statement), maplist(write, OutWords)).
```

But I don't know how to save all possibible Statements into file line by line.
Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy trick to emit all solutions is to **force backtracking** via `false/0`.

For example, *assuming* you have a predicate that yields all solutions on backtracking:

```
?- solution(S).
```

you can emit *all* solutions like this:

```
?- solution(S),
   print_solution(S),
   false.
```

where you have to define `print_solution/1` as you want to yield the format you desire.

For example, you can print such solutions to standard output and then **pipe** the output to a file. The specifics for this depend on your Prolog system and could look like this:

```
$ prolog --goal 'ignore((solution(S),portray_clause(S),false)),halt' > output.txt
```

Comment: The "false" solved generate-all problem. 
Can you help me with what is faster (to request all variables different, specify A must be [a,e,i,o] for example, or first to find words in dictionary ?)

Comment: Please file a separate question for this. Also, try using `time/1` to measure the time it takes, such as `?- time(your_goal).` . This will help you to find out which method is faster.